# Shell Scripting - Anonymous Block

Tags: sql, shell, plsql, ksh

I have a procedure that does a certain task and exits. 
The procedure has to be replicated to around 40 databases, that will run this procedure.
My concern is that if there is a change all across, every procedure has to be changed.

How can I create a shell script, that takes input 
username, password and SID and runs an anonymous block (the same procedure is converted as an anonymous block and put on server)
and it runs it.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I sometimes use:

```
dbs_list="
DB1.USR1
DB2.USR2
"
for x in ${dbs_list}
do
  DB_=` echo ${x}|cut -f "1" -d . `
  USR=` echo ${x}|cut -f "2" -d . `
  echo "################################               #### "
  echo "#processinb ${USR} @ ${DB_} --   ...#"
  echo "enter password:"
  read -s PWD
  sqlplus ${USR}/${PWD}@${DB_} << _EOF
    set serveroutput on
    prompt HERE is my anonymous code block
    begin
      dbms_output.put_line('do my things');
    end;
    /
_EOF
done
```

Note the importance:

- to have this `/` thing at the end of the PLSQL code block
- to have this last `_EOF` thing at the very beginning of the line after the sqlplus pseudo-file block (or so called famous [Here-document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) )

Hope this helps.